# Rails - correct way to refer to current model instance inside of methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model, instance

Suppose I have a `Post` model and I'd like to run a method when it's saved

in `post.rb` I do:

```
:before_save some_method_on_post

def some_method_on_post
  # Do something here
end
```

My question is, how do I refer to the current instantiated Post object inside of the method?

Edit: so to clarify suppose I wanted to do this:

```
def some_method_on_post
  post.some_property = foo
end
```

Do I refer to `post` as self?

Comment: Instance methods always refer to the object instance in question. That's what `self` should be defined as. What's the confusion here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Yes.

When using an attribute setting method, you refer to `self` as in method

```
def self.attribute_name=(value)
  @attribute_name = value
end
```

As a shortcut convenience, when you have a method that retrieves but does not set the object (so a getter), you can omit the `self`, e.g.

```
def attribute_name
  @the_value
end
```

Comment: As a note, `self` is analogous to `this` in JavaScript and other languages.